Confusing declined flags: proposed actions taken despite declining
As I was reviewing my flagging history, I noticed multiple flags that I raised on posts with the status-review tag were declined with the generic decline message*. Interestingly, the intended actions (or similar resolutions) were eventually taken on the posts despite the declined flags.
While I understand that declined flags can result in temporary flagging ban, my main concern is understanding the discrepancy. Looking for some insight into what might have caused this outcome, either on my part when flagging or during the review by moderators.

Here's a list of declined flags (linked to the respective posts):

Not MSE related. Status-Planned should be removed. - Status tag is removed and the question is now closed as "pertains only to a specific site". (enough details was provided)

Should be tagged -completed. - It is now tagged as completed (meta sites were updated a while back and from the body of the question it is obvious that the flair is now working)

Should be tagged -completed. - It is now tagged as completed. (rollback functionality exists on tag wikis)

Should be tagged -completed. - It is now tagged as completed. (although something that has been resolved for years, I guess more details could be helpful in this case)

Should be tagged -declined or -nonrepo. - Question is now closed as "no longer reproducible". (there is an answer by staff explaining the changes which makes this FR obsolete)

Should be tagged -completed. - It is now tagged as completed. (there's an answer by staff)

Should be tagged -completed. - This is closed as "no longer reproducible" (there's an answer by staff stating that the changes were reverted)


There were 2 more declined .. flags, asking for status-completed that I do understand why they were declined going back to them now.

I also reviewed similar flags that were marked as helpful, and I couldn't find any fundamental difference between these and the aforementioned ones:

Should be tagged -completed. - It is now tagged as completed.

Should be tagged -completed. - It is now tagged as completed; however, the mod message on the flag reads: "Helpful - Not sure if this is indeed fixed or just working right now, so not re-tagging it."

status-planned should be moved to the dupe-target, or at least that question should also get the tag. - Status review tag is removed from the duplicate but not added to the dupe-target!

This issue is resolved. Should be tagged as -completed. - It is now tagged as completed.

Considering the overhaul of image sharing service altogether, this should get status-completed or -deferred - Status tag is removed and questions is closed as "no longer reproducible".



 * "Declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it" 

I'm not the moderator who handled these flags, but I will note that the reason that a number of these posts received attention (some aligning with your requests, some not) about 2 months after these flags' handling date was during the concerted effort on the CMs' part to ensure status tags applied to old backlog items aligned with the internal backlog status. That work was a precursor to the status tag clarity effort that was more recently posted.

Well, this is usually not a moderator's place to mark something as completed (or rejected), but rather staff. So unless you give a strong evidence that the bug/request is actually completed already, they can't mark it as such only based on a single request. To support this, note that all your examples were marked completed by staff, not a mod.

Preface: I didn't handle those flags; I wasn't a mod at the time. I did speak with the handling mod, but I'm not going to speak for them here (except for one flag). I'll just break things down a bit from my POV, and I'll take a second to talk about our (well, at least my) approach to status tags and handling flags about them.

Status tags are hard for us. One of the main reasons for that is... Well, we're not employed by the company. Shadow kinda hit the nail on the head here. We don't have access to the internal issue trackers they have, and we can't see what work actually went into a given ticketed bug report/feature request, unless those changes are very obviously present somewhere we can see. Even in that case, we'd generally like to give staff the opportunity to follow up on questions related to their internal tickets in a way that makes sense to them/the company's goals. Status tags are the way the company communicates how the internal version of a given work item looks (and clarifying how they're meant to be used was a recent big-ticket item for the CM team). When we don't have the full picture, changing status tags accurately is hard.
For an example of how difficult managing status tags can be, let's look at this report about the transcript for a recent podcast episode not being available. A flag came in asking for status-review, and I obliged. We've done this song and dance before. A short while passes and, whaddaya know; sure looks to me like a transcript's there. So... status-completed right? Well, maybe a staff member wants to come along and explain why the podcast didn't debut with a transcript available? Maybe the transcript's going to disappear in a mushroom cloud, and the tag's suddenly going to be inappropriate. Yeah... I'm being a bit unreasonable there, but we don't really know. And that's tough when you're managing status tags on the mod end.
That example's a much more recent one, and thus the reasoning of "Let staff communicate change how they want to communicate it" becomes a bit less relevant as time goes on. Things fall through the cracks, changes happen that 99% fix a thing but don't 100% resolve it, so maybe staff don't feel following up is appropriate... Stuff like that. Your flags were on older posts (the most recent post was about 5 years ago), and while the argument that we should let staff do their thing becomes weaker, I'd still say I'd prefer staff handle these in a way they feel is appropriate, especially if it was escalated via status-review, or retagged by staff if it predates the escalation process (as that indicates to me they've got it on their radar... Somewhere).
So, generally, I only retag to status-completed when it's super obvious that all the work is done (and maybe most of the communication of that work being done is done, but that's mostly optional on really old stuff). Further, I'd really appreciate not having to go and find that proof of work being done. If a flag adequately explains why a particular thing is fixed, or a given change in tags is necessary, I'm really appreciative. We do let a lot of flags that request status tags sit for awhile (yours sat for a little over a month) so staff have the opportunity to handle them if they're in the neighborhood, but we'd rather not pull CMs aside and poke them about these requests (especially on old stuff) because we'd like to try and value their time. Cleanup on ancient tickets is important, but isn't something we'd like to make a habit of prodding CMs about.

Right, so, with all that wordy nonsense out of the way, let's take a closer look at the flags you raised. First, here's some general knowledge so folks have the full context:

All of your flags were raised on March 28th
All of your flags were handled on April 30th
The changes made to these questions by staff at a later date were made independent of the flags you raised (unless they looked at the flag history, which is unlikely IMO)

As a bit of general advice, I'd prefer if you don't go hunting for questions that need a retag. Try and find them organically, or flag stuff that you were personally involved in. It's okay to do a little bit of this (cleanup can be important), but I'd generally prefer if you didn't do this in batch format like this. I'm not factoring that into the explanations for the handling (flags are handled on their merit alone, not their frequency of course), I'm just tossing this out as general advice.
A somewhat common theme in my responses is going to be "Please include more detail". Unless it's super obvious that a thing was fixed, you didn't really give us too much to go on. Sometimes that's okay, but more detail is always appreciated. It makes our job a bunch easier.
Declined flags:


Not MSE related. Status-Planned should be removed. - Status tag is removed and the question is now closed as "pertains only to a specific site". (enough details was provided)


This one's kinda difficult. Pawel, a staff member at the time, was doing a lot of managing of the status tags there. I'd generally agree that the status tag should go, but it was a bit difficult to tell what was really going on with the work that was being done there, and/or how staff wanted to communicate that. It turns out your hunch was right, but it's tough.


Should be tagged -completed. - It is now tagged as completed (meta sites were updated a while back and from the body of the question it is obvious that the flair is now working)


I think I'd have agreed with you here. While we couldn't have known that "all work on this is done", I think it's reasonable to assume this was fixed.


Should be tagged -completed. - It is now tagged as completed. (rollback functionality exists on tag wikis)


I spoke with the mod who handled this one, and they explained that they looked to the comment here and noted that the OP appeared to not see a rollback option. I know that you know that rollbacks are available on tag wikis, but explaining that in your flag description (maybe with a link to the rev list of an example tag) would have helped solidify a tag change here.


Should be tagged -completed. - It is now tagged as completed. (although something that has been resolved for years, I guess more details could be helpful in this case)


I agree with you: More detail would've been great here. I don't think I, as someone with a profile on every site, can even reproduce getting that popup to appear without making a sock. Further, I don't use MacOS or Safari (I use Chrome, though!) so I can't go off and test it easily.


Should be tagged -declined or -nonrepo. - Question is now closed as "no longer reproducible". (there is an answer by staff explaining the changes which makes this FR obsolete)


You flagged asking for -declined or -norepro, but it's unclear whether those tags are actually appropriate. Slate went for just closing the question as no longer reproducible, which is appropriate since "Changes affecting the asker have rendered (it) obsolete", but -norepro isn't appropriate since this isn't really a bug report. You could make an argument for -declined, but some work was done, it just went in a different direction (by obviating this request). Interpretation of this one is tough, so declining the flag (i.e. taking a "I'm not touching this one" approach) seems fine to me here.


Should be tagged -completed. - It is now tagged as completed. (there's an answer by staff)


Yeah there's an answer by staff, but it cites ongoing work. There was no evidence here that they're 100% done with whatever they're working on.


Should be tagged -completed. - This is closed as "no longer reproducible" (there's an answer by staff stating that the changes were reverted)


Manually checking this functionality is tough. Not having enough details about this being fixed to go on here made taking a "do nothing" approach appropriate here. There's no update from staff indicating changes were made that accomplish this.
Mainly, I'd just ask that you supply more info in your flag descriptions. For some of these I might have personally written out a non-canned explanation for the decline, but for 6/7 of these I completely see why the handling mod went the direction they did.
For the helpful flags where you had trouble understanding why your proposed action was taken despite similar circumstances...
Helpful flags:


Should be tagged -completed. - It is now tagged as completed.


The staff answer there is pretty clear-cut.


Should be tagged -completed. - It is now tagged as completed; however, the mod message on the flag reads: "Helpful - Not sure if this is indeed fixed or just working right now, so not re-tagging it."


Given this answer it seemed that top bar adjustments are... Fickle. Determining whether all the work needing to make this bug report done is, well, done, might be difficult if we don't have all the knowledge staff do.


status-planned should be moved to the dupe-target, or at least that question should also get the tag. - Status review tag is removed from the duplicate but not added to the dupe-target!


Well, is the dupe target really planned? Or is it done? Is there any work ongoing? What reason do you have for thinking this has ongoing work being done? The mod just dismissed this one as helpful, but I honestly would've declined it. I don't think we have enough to go on to make any changes here. Staff might (and made a decision to just remove the tag) but we don't have the inside scoop on this.


This issue is resolved. Should be tagged as -completed. - It is now tagged as completed.


A staff answer there indicated that work was forthcoming, and it's a lot easier to (attempt to) reproduce this issue than others.


Considering the overhaul of image sharing service altogether, this should get status-completed or -deferred - Status tag is removed and questions is closed as "no longer reproducible".


I don't think -completed fits since I don't think ask #3 is done, and circumstances have obviated the request (hence the closure by the community). I don't think -deferred fits since... Well, imgur was completely replaced, so I don't really think ask #3 was really addressed by the work done, it was circumvented. Unless it was done and we just don't know about it. I think the mod dismissed this one as helpful since, sure, some sort of retag might be appropriate, but no action was really needed at this time.

I hope this helps explain how some of these were handled and how we (or at least I) like to approach these. I... Apologize a bit for the length.
I'm always open to clarifying questions in the comments. I'm big on transparency, so if I didn't adequately respond to anything please do poke me. We can hop in chat if that's a more acceptable venue as well.

As a former mod, unless you yoloed the cat out of it, can confirm status tags were hard :D. There's very little visibility of the inner aspects of the company from a mod's perspective at the level one would need to handle it - and sometimes I suspect staff might not know even, either cause of unforeseen circumstances or time. The best we can do, is the best we can do, so to speak

I actually appreciate the length :) Took me a while to read it, but it gave a very detailed explanation both in general and case by case. Couldn't hope for a better answer. Thank you.
